# Error: Call to a member function addDays() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add days on specified date. This is my code:

```
if (Carbon::now() <= $campaign->s_lastrun->addDays(28)) {
       $onAir = 1;
}
```

It worked until I made some changes on my database, and now I am getting an error: `Call to a member function addDays() on string` even though `s_lastrun` has column type `DATE`.
Any ideas?

Comment: What changes did you make to your database?

Comment: And what changes did you make?

Comment: if `s_lastrun` is of type `DATE`, this field will not behave as a Carbon date. You need that field to be of type `timestamp`. You can first do a `Carbon::parse()` and do what's needed alternatively.

Comment: I forgot to include `s_lastrun` in model's `$dates` array... @aynber's solution helped me.

Comment: I was gonna to, but it needed 4-5 minutes to pass :) thx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell Eloquent that it's a date, so that it will convert it to Carbon. Per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators):

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which extends the PHP DateTime class to provide an assortment of helpful methods. You may customize which dates are automatically mutated, and even completely disable this mutation, by overriding the $dates property of your model.

So in your model, add the following:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 's_lastrun'];
```

Remove `created_at` and `updated_at` if you aren't using the default time stamps.

Answer (score 10):

Since `addDays()` can't be applied to string variable,

You have to parse `$campaign->s_lastrun` using Carbon like this:

```
Carbon::parse($campaign->s_lastrun)
```

and then compare like this:

```
if (Carbon::now() <= Carbon::parse($campaign->s_lastrun)->addDays(28)) {
   $onAir = 1;
}
```

Comment: Or use the `lte()` function.